# Shuffle value inside Loop and concatenate with array

Tags: php, arrays

I do have a requirement where in Inside an array i need to shuffle the values.

Below is the code Snippet

```
$vehicle = array('hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv');
$RequiredVehicle = 3;

$vehicleList = array();


for($i=0;$i<count($vehicle);$i++)
{
  $vehicleList[] =$vehicle[$i].$RequiredVehicle;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($vehicleList);
```

The Output what i am getting is

```
Array
(
    [0] => hcv3
    [1] => hcv3
    [2] => hcv3
    [3] => hcv3
    [4] => hcv3
    [5] => hcv3
    [6] => hcv3
    [7] => hcv3
    [8] => hcv3
    [9] => hcv3
)
```

The Actual output what i need is

```
Array
(
    [0] => hcv1
    [1] => hcv2
    [2] => hcv3
    [3] => hcv1
    [4] => hcv2
    [5] => hcv3
    [6] => hcv1
    [7] => hcv2
    [8] => hcv3
    [9] => hcv1
)
```

There are **10** vehicles and **3** Required vehicles so The output what i need is total vehicles should be shuffled between 3 Required vehicles

if its $vehicle = 10 and $RequiredVehicle = 3 then Array value should be
**1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1**

if its $vehicle = 10 and $RequiredVehicle = 2 then Array value should be
**1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are just appending the `$RequiredVehicle`

You can use modulo `%` the `$i` and add 1. Like `( ( $i % $RequiredVehicle ) + 1 )`

```
$vehicle = array('hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv');
$RequiredVehicle = 3;

$vehicleList = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($vehicle);$i++)
{
   $vehicleList[] =$vehicle[$i] . ( ( $i % $RequiredVehicle ) + 1 );
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($vehicleList);
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hcv1
    [1] => hcv2
    [2] => hcv3
    [3] => hcv1
    [4] => hcv2
    [5] => hcv3
    [6] => hcv1
    [7] => hcv2
    [8] => hcv3
    [9] => hcv1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

hopefully it will provide your actual output :)

```
 $vehicle = array('hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv','hcv');
$RequiredVehicle = 3;

$vehicleList = array();

$j = 1 ;
for($i=0;$i<count($vehicle);$i++)
{

  $vehicleList[] =$vehicle[$i].$j++;
  if($j > $RequiredVehicle){
     $j=1;
}
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($vehicleList);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hcv1
    [1] => hcv2
    [2] => hcv3
    [3] => hcv1
    [4] => hcv2
    [5] => hcv3
    [6] => hcv1
    [7] => hcv2
    [8] => hcv3
    [9] => hcv1
)
```